# How to append table to a xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, html, xml-parsing

I want to be able to append a whole table with a set of attributes to a xml file, so I be able to retrieve them later. The only problem I am facing is to write to the XML file, while when I call alert() on the stored values, they are set correctly.

Here is my code:

```
  function getXML(positionX, positionY, canvasWidth, canvasHeight) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            xmlParse(xhttp);
            addToXml(xhttp, positionX, positionY, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "index.xml", true);
        xhttp.send();
    };




     function addToXml(xml, positionX, positionY, canvasWidth, canvasHeight) {
            var xmlFile = xml.responseXML;
            var table = xmlFile.createElement("table"),
                x = xmlFile.createAttribute("positionX"),
                y = xmlFile.createAttribute("positionY"),
                width = xmlFile.createAttribute("tableWidth"),
                height = xmlFile.createAttribute("tableheight");
            x.nodeValue = positionX;
            y.nodeValue = positionY;
            width.nodeValue = canvasWidth;
            height.nodeValue = canvasHeight;


            table.setAttributeNode(x);
            table.setAttributeNode(y);
            table.setAttributeNode(width);
            table.setAttributeNode(height);

            xmlFile.getElementsByTagName('Tables')[0].appendChild(table);
            alert(xmlFile.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getAttribute('positionX'));

        }
```